# On a custom exception, how is __str__ defined?

Tags: python, exception

On a course I found the following piece of code:

```
class Ex(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        Exception.__init__(self, msg + msg)
        self.args = (msg,) 
try:
    raise Ex('ex')
except Ex as e:
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Reading that, I thought that printing **e** would show **exex**, but it's only **ex**.

Shouldn't the **msg + msg** change it to **exex**?

Comment: @Chris because line 3 is concatenating msg twice.

Comment: You are manually setting `.args` to `self.args = (msg,) ` If you remove that line, it prints `exex`

Comment: Seems like `super().__init__(msg + msg)`  without messing with `.args` is better pattern.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah that was it. __str__ is set by args[0] (which I didn't know) and I hadn't fully realized that the next line is setting args.

Comment: @MarkMeyer it's just an example made to confuse the student. Which clearly worked on me.

Comment: @motionsickness well, no exactly, look at the answer, the `__str__` will either return an empty string if `args` is an empty tuple, or the first item if it is a tuple of length one, or just the stringified tuple if it is a multi-element tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseException.__str__` is defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/674fa0a740151e0416c9383f127b16014e805990/Objects/exceptions.c#L108-L119)

```c
static PyObject *
BaseException_str(PyBaseExceptionObject *self)
{
    switch (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self->args)) {
    case 0:
        return PyUnicode_FromString("");
    case 1:
        return PyObject_Str(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(self->args, 0));
    default:
        return PyObject_Str(self->args);
    }
}
```

roughly translated into pseudocode:

```py
def __str__(self) -> str:
    if len(self.args) == 0:
        return ''
    elif len(self.args) == 1:
        return str(self.args[0])
    else:
        return str(self.args)
```

so in this case, even though you initialize `Exception.__init__` with a doubling of msg, you immediately clobber `self.args` with the original value

if you `print(self.args)` before you assign it, you'll see your doubled message

if you remove your `self.args` assignment you'll get the value you expect